# DB Design Question

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I am designing an Org Chart, model is almost ready and simplified a bit for clarity here.

```
OrgUnit (OrgUnitId, Name, ReportsToOrgUnitId, ...)
OrgUnitJobs (OrgUnitJobId, OrgUnitId, JobName, ReportsToOrgUnitJobId, ... ,IsJobGroup)
Employee (EmployeeId, ........)
OrgUnitJobEmployee (OrgUnitJobId, EmployeeId, AssignedDate, .....,)
```

so I want to know every OrgUnit's ManagerEmployee (should have one), and Employees can have more than one job, but one of them has to be the main job, so I know whats his manager and other stuff.
This is going to support a little workflow behind the scnese, so that is why it is not a very simple Org chart Model.

so what would you do, would you add properties like (IsManager property to OrgUnitJobs model) or add ManagerOrgUnitJobId to OrgUnitModel. and why?

Likewise, for employees would you add IsPrimaryJob property to OrgUnitJobEmployee model, or add PrimaryJobId to Employee Model.

Comment: Can't think of anything to add right now, but I like the look of this schema - most realistic org chart schema I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding 2 more tables (though i may be missing something):

```
OrgUnitManagers(OrgUnitJobID)  
OrgUnitJobEmployeeMain(OrgUnitJobEmployeeID)
```

Can use referential integrity setting to ensure if an OrgUnitJob or OrgUnitJobEmployee record's are deleted these tables are updated automatically (if available on your DB)

*-OR-*

```
OrgUnitManager(OrgUnitJobID, OrgUnitId)  
OrgUnitJobEmployeeMain(EmployeeId, OrgUnitJobID)
```

Can use referential integrity and now indexes to ensure uniqueness, though theres now duplication in the schema

*Im a little confused as to whether the manager is specified at the OrgUnitJob level or at the OrgUnitJobEmployeeID level?? The above assumes its at the OrgUnitJob, but if its at the employee level, change OrgUnitManagers(OrgUnitJobID) to OrgUnitManagers(OrgUnitJobEmployeeID)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly understanding the manager concept. Is a manager an employee or an organizational unit? Depending on your answer I'd have a ManagerEmployeeId or a ManagerOrgUnitJobId property on OrgUnit and/or OrgUnitJobs.

I would add PrimaryJobId to the Employee. That guarantees an employee only has **one** primary job.

So I guess in both cases I would favor an XxxId-type property over a boolean IsXxx property.  An IsXxx property opens the door for multiple managers or multiple primary jobs.

Comment: Multiple managers happens in the Real World so it's good that the schema allows for it.

Comment: ManagerOrgUnitJob is a Job defined for that OrgUnit just like any other jobs in that org unit, but it is unique and it should show the manager job position for that OrgUnit.
In the end, Manager is an employee (filling in that job position).
I dont want to treat Management Job position any different than other jobs so I can keep a history of the employee's job changes in the organization.